# Definition error while using instance of class that is in an if loop

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors, while-loop, undefined

----I have two instances of NSString, and one of them is defined within a while loop, but the other one is after that. Xcode seems to think that since this first instance (we'll call string1) is in a while loop, it will not be defined. However, for the program to proceed out of the while loop IT WILL ALWAYS DEFINE STRING1. An NSString is in another while loop thats the same thing.

----Outside of both while loops, at the end, in the code I have a method of NSString done to both of them (isEqualtoString), but Xcode tells me that string1 and string two are not defined. The program should work, but the compiler stops me. Is there anything I can change to make string1 and string2 appear defined in Xcode's eyes.

----I'm using this for the registration page, and I need these in while loops because they need to cycle until the user enters in through the console a username that fits my requirements.

EDIT: Added in actual code.

```
int numb1, numb2;

char usercheck1[60];
char usercheck2[60];
//Registration
    numb2 = 1;
    while (numb2 == 1){
        numb1 = 1;
        while (numb1 == 1){
            numb1 = 0;
            NSLog(@"Username:");
            fgets(usercheck1, sizeof usercheck1, stdin);
            int c2;
            while((c2 = getchar()) != '\n' && c2 != EOF);
            if (usercheck1 [sizeof (usercheck1)-1] == '\n'){ // In case that the input string has 12 characters plus '\n'
               usercheck1 [sizeof (usercheck1)-1] = '\0';} // Plus '\0', the '\n' isn't added and the if condition is false.
            NSString* string1 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: usercheck1];
            //Makes sure string contains no spaces and string length is correct size.
            if ([string1 length] > 12){
               NSLog (@"Username must be 12 characters or less!");
               numb1 = 1;}
            if ([string1 length] < 5){
               NSLog (@"Username must be 4 characters or more!");
               numb1 = 1;}
            if ([string1 rangeOfString:@" " ].location != NSNotFound){
               NSLog(@"Username cannot contain spaces!");
               numb1 = 1;}
      }
        numb1 = 1;
        while (numb1 == 1){
            numb1 = 0;
            NSLog(@"Confirm Username:");
            fgets(usercheck2, sizeof usercheck2, stdin);
            int c2;
            while((c2 = getchar()) != '\n' && c2 != EOF);
            if (usercheck2 [sizeof (usercheck2)-1] == '\n'){ // In case that the input string has 12 characters plus '\n'
            usercheck2 [sizeof (usercheck2)-1] = '\0';} // Plus '\0', the '\n' isn't added and the if condition is false.
            NSString* string2 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: usercheck2];
            //Makes sure string contains no spaces and string length is correct size.
            if ([string2 length] > 12){
               NSLog (@"Username must be 12 characters or less!");
               numb1 = 1;}
            if ([string2 length] < 5){
               NSLog (@"Username must be 4 characters or more!");
               numb1 = 1;}
            if ([string2 rangeOfString:@" " ].location != NSNotFound){
               NSLog(@"Username cannot contain spaces!");
               numb1 = 1;}
        }
        if ([string2 isEqualToString: string1] == YES){
            NSLog(@"Usernames confirmed! Username:%s", string2);
            numb2 = 0;}
        else {NSLog(@"Usernames do not match. Try again");
            numb2 = 1;}
    }

}
```

As you can see, it would work if it actually compiled and ran, but the compiler just doesn't like me using string2 in the if statement for isEqualToString. It gives me the error :
"Use of undeclared identifier 'string2'"
Also, move that statement and the else statment outside the two sub-while statements, it gives me that error for BOTH string1 and string2.

XCode version is 4.6.3, I'm programming for the Mac OS X on 10.8.4

Comment: Since you're having compiler errors, actual code would probably be more helpful (if it's not too long). As it is, in your "pseudo-code", you don't actually declare string1 _or_ string2.

Comment: Sorry @Pat Lillis, I thought it might be easier if I had that instead. I'll make it within a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access variables outside of the scope in which they are declared. Since `string1` and `string2` are declared within the two `while` blocks, you can't use them outside of the `while` blocks.

There are many things that could be improved in this code. Try something like this:

```
NSString *username1;
NSString *username2;
while (1) {
    while (1) {
        NSLog(@"Username:");
        char usercheck[60];
        fgets(usercheck, sizeof usercheck1, stdin);

        int c2;
        while ((c2 = getchar()) != '\n' && c2 != EOF);
        if (usercheck [sizeof (usercheck) - 1] == '\n') { // In case that the input string has 12 characters plus '\n'
           usercheck[sizeof (usercheck)-1] = '\0';
        } // Plus '\0', the '\n' isn't added and the if condition is false.

        NSString *string1 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:usercheck];
        // Makes sure string contains no spaces and string length is correct size.
        if ([string1 length] > 12) {
           NSLog(@"Username must be 12 characters or less!");
        } else if ([string1 length] < 5) {
           NSLog(@"Username must be 4 characters or more!");
        } else if ([string1 rangeOfString:@" "].location != NSNotFound) {
           NSLog(@"Username cannot contain spaces!");
        } else {
           username1 = string1;
           break; // username is good
        }
    }

    while (1) {
        NSLog(@"Confirm Username:");
        char usercheck[60];
        fgets(usercheck, sizeof usercheck, stdin);

        int c2;
        while ((c2 = getchar()) != '\n' && c2 != EOF);
        if (usercheck[sizeof (usercheck) - 1] == '\n') { // In case that the input string has 12 characters plus '\n'
            usercheck[sizeof (usercheck) - 1] = '\0';
        } // Plus '\0', the '\n' isn't added and the if condition is false.

        NSString *string2 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:usercheck];
        //Makes sure string contains no spaces and string length is correct size.
        if ([string2 length] > 12) {
           NSLog (@"Username must be 12 characters or less!");
        } else if ([string2 length] < 5) {
           NSLog (@"Username must be 4 characters or more!");
        } else if ([string2 rangeOfString:@" "].location != NSNotFound) {
           NSLog(@"Username cannot contain spaces!");
        } else {
           username2 = string2;
           break;
        }
    }

    if ([username1 isEqualToString:username2]) {
        NSLog(@"Usernames confirmed! Username:%@", username1);
        break;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Usernames do not match. Try again");
    }
}
```

Comment: Using those breaks does make the while blocks way easier then the system I was trying to use, and the answer to my question works smoother. Thanks! :D I have two questions though. What does the `(1)` after the `while` block do? And how do you do `char usercheck[60]` inside of the `while` block? I thought usercheck was immutable...?

Comment: `while (1)` means to loop forever (since `1` is always "true"). Declaring `usercheck` inside the `while` loop is no different than what you had other than changing the scope. Variables should be declared in the scope they are used in. There was no need to declare them as early as you did. There is nothing immutable about `usercheck`. It simply declares an array of 60 characters. Anywhere in the block you can manipulate the elements of the array.